# Entrando em case errado

Tags: java, for, switch, break

Estou fazendo um exercício em Java que pede para cadastrar, salário, imposto e sair. Utilizei um `switch` case para tal, claro e até ai tudo bem.

Entretanto quando executo e coloco para cadastrar o Java percorre o `case 1` e antes mesmo que eu coloque o nome do indivíduo ele já pula para o `case 2`.

Eu coloquei `break`, tentei fazer com um `if` para não ter de criar outro case, entretanto ocorre a mesma coisa quando tem o `if` dentro do `case 1`.

Eu não consigo entender porque ele não espera o cara informar o nome para depois disso passar para o próximo código.

Vou colocar o código abaixo:

```
while(true) {
        System.out.println("Escolha \"1\" para cadastro; \"2\" para informar salário; \"3\" para calcular imposto; \"0\" para sair!");
        choice = scan.nextInt();

        choiceProgram: //LabeledLoops

        switch(choice) {

        case 1:
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Informe o nome do indivíduo: ");
                listaFuncionarios.add(scan.nextLine());
                break choiceProgram;
            }
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Informe o nome: ");
            nome = scan.nextLine();
            nome = nome.toLowerCase();

            for(int i = 0; i < listaFuncionarios.size(); i++) {
                if(listaFuncionarios.equals(nome)) {
                    indice = i;
                    status = true;
                    break;
                }else if((i + 1) == listaFuncionarios.size() && status == false) {
                    System.out.println("Nome não encontrado!");
                    break choiceProgram;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Informe o salário de " + listaFuncionarios.get(indice));
            listaSalario.set(indice, scan.nextDouble());
            break choiceProgram;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Informe o nome do indivíduo que deseja calcular o imposto sobre salário: ");
            nome = scan.nextLine();
            nome = nome.toLowerCase();

            for(int i = 0; i < listaFuncionarios.size(); i++) {
                if(listaFuncionarios.equals(nome)) {
                    indice = i;
                    valor = listaSalario.get(indice);
                    status = true;
                    break;
                }else if((i + 1) == listaFuncionarios.size() && status == false) {
                    System.out.println("Nome não encontrado!");
                    break choiceProgram;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(listaFuncionarios.get(indice) + " recebe " + listaSalario.get(indice) + "\nCalculando o desconto do imposto, seu salário final é: " + Operacoes.Imposto(valor));

            break choiceProgram;

        case 0:
            System.out.println("O programa será finalizado!");
            break mainProgram;

        }

    }
```

Sinceramente eu não tenho ideia do que ocorre e como eu posso fazer isso resolver. Sim, no `break choiceProgram` (*labeled loops*) dá erro com ou sem isso. Vou botar uma imagem do console:

[image: erro switch case]

Comment: Acredito que deveria ter um `break`  ali fora do `while` no primeiro case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há conflitos do `break` do `case` e do `for` que possuem funções um pouco diferentes. Tem várias formas de resolver, mas a mais correta é separar isto em métodos, assim não mistura os dois tipos de `break`:

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Escolha \"1\" para cadastro; \"2\" para informar salário; \"3\" para calcular imposto; \"0\" para sair!");
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        Cadastro();
        break;
    case 2:
        Salario();
        break;
    case 3:
        Imposto();
        break;
    case 0:
        System.out.println("O programa será finalizado!");
        break mainProgram; //dá para fazer melhor que isto, mas não vi o resto
    }
}
```

Depois:

```
private void Cadastro() {
    System.out.println("Informe o nome do indivíduo: ");
    listaFuncionarios.add(scan.nextLine());
}
private void Salario() {
    System.out.println("Informe o nome: ");
    nome = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaFuncionarios.size(); i++) {
        if (listaFuncionarios.equals(nome)) {
            indice = i;
            status = true;
            break;
        } else if ((i + 1) == listaFuncionarios.size() && !status) {
            System.out.println("Nome não encontrado!");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Informe o salário de " + listaFuncionarios.get(indice));
    listaSalario.set(indice, scan.nextDouble());
}
private void Imposto() {
    System.out.println("Informe o nome do indivíduo que deseja calcular o imposto sobre salário: ");
    nome = scan.nextLine()nome.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaFuncionarios.size(); i++) {
        if (listaFuncionarios.equals(nome)) {
            indice = i;
            valor = listaSalario.get(indice);
            status = true;
            break;
        } else if ((i + 1) == listaFuncionarios.size() && !status) {
            System.out.println("Nome não encontrado!");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listaFuncionarios.get(indice) + " recebe " + listaSalario.get(indice) + "\nCalculando o desconto do imposto, seu salário final é: " + Operacoes.Imposto(valor));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Switch.java).

Evite `break` nomeado sempre que possível. No caso é mais fácil fazer sem ele, então faça sem ele. Só o use quando fica mais fácil usá-lo.

Eu vejo outros problemas neste código, mas isto é outro assunto. Inclusive desta forma provavelmente terá que mudar a declaração das variáveis que não estão declaradas no lugar certo. Mas não posso ajudar nesta parte até porque o código colocado não tem tudo o que é necessário, e não parece ser o foco da pergunta.

Comment: entendi. Eu pensei em adicionar as informações no ArrayList antes de utilizar um método. Mas pelo que vejo o case causa esse tipo de situação quase sempre.

Eu também tentei usar o LabeledLoops para que o break quebrasse a execução da parte exata que eu desejo. Isso parece funcionar. 
Vou fazer o que você está propondo pq não vejo alternativa, mas gostaria de saber uma forma disso não ocorrer sem ter de apelar para um método.

Comment: Na verdade esse código todo é confuso, mas como eu disse, não tenho como ajudar mais. Eu começaria fazer de novo agora de forma mais organizada, mas precisa aprender organizar código antes. Tem `flags`, tem um índice que parece esquisito, e algumas outras coisas.

Comment: eu só postei a parte relacionada ao erro. Acima desse código tem as variáveis e os ArrayLists sendo criado.

Comment: me tira só uma dúvida @bigown, eu necessariamente tenho de criar as ArrayLists dentro do main ou pode ser criada no método que está fora do programa principal? E se eu criar no método tem como fazer com que outro método acesse esse ArrayList?

Comment: Depende do que quer fazer, mas isso nem faz parte da dúvida que você colocou. Pode retornar o *array*, pode fazer ele ficar na classe, mas não temos como saber sem entender o objetivo. Eu respondi o que foi perguntado. Agora você tem outra dúvida.

Comment: grato. Achei q poderia estender o caso já q faz parte da situação.

vou criar o ArrayList dentro do main, até pq tem vários métodos...